# How to stop appcelerator console window from taking focus

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Does anyone know how to stop the the console window in appcelerator studio from becoming the active window when a new status message comes through?

I'm editing code in one window and then without warning i'm typing in the console window because a new console message came through. Even if I close the console window it will pop back open whenever a new log message comes though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I found some options under preferences->Console/Debug/Console that should fixed the issue.  Uncheck

Show when a program writes to standard error
Show when a program writes to standard output